# is it possible to install elastic search in localhost Magento 2.3.4 p2 version

Tags: configuration, installation, elasticsearch, localhost, magento2.3.4-p2

> Hi All, i read documentation from [devdocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html) that how to install
> elastic search. For this i have install java jdk package in my
> localhost and now i am trying to install elastic search latest version
> using cmd but it's taking too much time(it's around 6 hours now).
>
> I wanted to know that is elastic search will work on localhost or not.
> because i tried port `localhost:9200` in my local machine it's running
> please check in below screenshot and even configured it in Magento
> 2.3.4 p2 version in backend and it's showing `Successful! Test again?` with same
> host `localhost:9200` without completion of elastic search setup.
>
> If any idea on it please suggest me.

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have already installed and configured all you need

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Elasticsearch in my Linux Mint & It's working fine. Here is the steps.

Run the below command to Install Elasticsearch In locally.

Download and install the public signing key :

`wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -`

Installing from the APT repositoryedit

You may need to install the apt-transport-https package on Debian before proceeding :

`sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`

Save the repository definition to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list :

`echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list`

You can install the Elasticsearch Debian package with :

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch`

Elasticsearch is not started automatically after installation. How to start and stop Elasticsearch depends on whether your system uses SysV `init` or `systemd` (used by newer distributions).

`ps -p 1`

Running Elasticsearch with SysV `init` : Use the `update-rc.d` command to configure Elasticsearch to start automatically when the system boots up :

`sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults 95 10`

Elasticsearch can be started and stopped using the `service` command :

`sudo -i service elasticsearch start`

`sudo -i service elasticsearch stop`

Configure Apache and Elasticsearch : Set up a proxy (Set up a proxy for Apache 2.4)

Enable mod_proxy as follows :

`a2enmod proxy_http` or `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`

Use a text editor to open /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Add the following directive at the top of the file :

`Listen 8080`

Add the following at the bottom of the file :

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://localhost:9200/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache :

`service apache2 restart` or `sudo service apache2 restart`

Verify the proxy works by entering the following command :

For example, if your proxy uses port 8080:

`curl -i http://localhost:8080/_cluster/health`

If curl request success then messages display like below :

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 23 Aug 2020 06:05:56 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 389

{"cluster_name":"elasticsearch","status":"yellow","timed_out":false,"number_of_nodes":1,"number_of_data_nodes":1,"active_primary_shards":1,"active_shards":1,"relocating_shards":0,"initializing_shards":0,"unassigned_shards":1,"delayed_unassigned_shards":0,"number_of_pending_tasks":0,"number_of_in_flight_fetch":0,"task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis":0,"active_shards_percent_as_number":50.0}

Go to `Admin Panel -> Stores -> Settings -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search`. Change the settings like below.

`Search Engine : Search Engine7`

`Elasticsearch Server Hostname : localhost`

`Elasticsearch Server Port : 8080`

`Elasticsearch Index Prefix : magento2`

`Enable Elasticsearch HTTP Auth : No`

`Elasticsearch Server Timeout : 15`

Now save the configuration & run below cache clean command.

`php bin/magento cache:clean`

Now click on `Test Connection` button.

After successful you will receive `Successful! Test again?` in `Test Connection` button.

Ref : [Dev Docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/es-config-apache.html) & [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html)

For More [Click here](https://vrajeshpatel.in/2020/08/23/magento-2-4-0-getting-error-could-not-validate-a-connection-to-elasticsearch/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can install it on localhost.
rl localhost:9200 If not installed then: sudo apt update

Then run the installation: sudo apt install elasticsearch

First, reload the systemd configuration: sudo systemctl daemon-reload

Then, enable the Elasticsearch service with: sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service

And finally, after the service is enabled, start Elasticsearch: sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service